# Unable to resolve UNC path of mapped drive while browsing files

Tags: windows, cmd, sas

I want to obtained the UNC path of a mapped drive using base SAS. Please suggest a way to obtain the fully qualified path by resolving the drive letter.

For eg. If I've mapped `\\mrllogon\system\phases\tools` to drive W, I am getting path as `W:\adhoc\programming` instead of `\\mrllogon\system\phases\tools\adhoc\programming`.
Please suggest a method to resolve this drive paths in Base SAS.

Comment: Not really a SAS question, but... 

Run a DOS `net use` command to see the mappings, pipe that into a datastep...

Comment: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2008/023-2008.pdf

Comment: @Reeza unfortunately OP mentioned he could not get Carpenter's approach to work when I suggested it over at https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/Unable-to-resolve-UNC-path-of-mapped-drive-while-browsing-files/td-p/248180 .  I haven't tried it myself yet.  What version of Windows are you running?